# error: Directory must be empty to GitHub init

Tags: github, lando

I'm having this issue trying to start with a Lando setup using Drupal8 and Github.

My steps to reproduce:

Created GitHub token, as described in documentation

Created a repo on GitHub (https://github.com/my_name/the_name.git). At first.

mkdir thename && cd thename

lando init github

? Enter a GitHub token [hidden]

? Which site? myaccount/thename

? What recipe do you want to use? drupal8

? Where is your webroot relative to the init destination? .

error: Directory must be empty to GitHub init.

Any idea to avoid this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your GitHub repo should be the destination (for future git push), not the source (to initialize a Lando local repo)

See [docs/cli/init](https://github.com/lando/lando/blob/master/docs/cli/init.md):

```
# Non interactively pull a site from github and set it up as a lamp site
lando init github \
  --recipe lamp \
  --github-auth MYTOKEN \
  --github-repo git@github.com:lando/lando.git \
  --dest ./ \
  --webroot .
```

The `github-repo` is one with a Lando app in it.